# Which Nightcrawler rescued Wolverine?

Tags: comics, marvel, wolverine

In Wolverine: Weapon X #9, Wolverine gets rescued from Dr Rot by Psylocke and Nightcrawler.  In Uncanny X-Force, it's the Age of Apocalypse Nightcrawler that had joined Psylocke, Wolverine, etc.  Is the Nightcrawler Wolverine is rescued by this one, or the original one?  I'm not sure how the various timelines interact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolverine: Weapon X #9 was published in March '10, and X-Force #26, where Kurt sacrifices himself, was published in June '10. Whilst the in-universe times of comics can be out of whack, this would only be an issue if the order of publishing was reversed. We could then question if the on-going story of Weapon X was effected by Uncanny X-men. However, the order that they are published we can be confident that the events of X-Force must take place after Wolverine: Weapon X.

Equally, from what I know AoA Kurt is a bit of a Jerk, with a 'I'm not *that* Kurt' chip on his shoulder, which would/should have flagged him up as different Kurt to you.

Comment: Haven't really read much X-Men with original Kurt to compare him with.

Comment: **Original Kurt**, nice: "In that moment, Charles Xavier gave me the most precious gift of all...a chance at LIFE. For this, I shall eternally remain in his debt."
**AoA Kurt**, Jerk: "I'm going to kill the b******s who ruined our lives. Sugar Man, Drake, McCoy, the Blob-- they're all here in this world. They think they're safe from retribution. They will learn otherwise."